GStreamer access buffers from synchronised RTP streams
I connect to an RTSP server that produces two RTP streams (same camera), one H.264 and another uncompressed raw video.  The streams are need to be used together on the client side.
On the client side, I use rtspsrc which I expect is synchronising the two streams as they come from the same RTSP server.
How can I access the raw data for both the decoded H.264 and the matching uncompressed raw video stream? To be clear, I am wondering how can I get the buffers for the two streams and guarantee they are the images that were originally simulateanously streamed over RTP?

I think this could be hard because, you will need some meta Data where you set the timestamp or frame Indicator before encoding the frame and also add this Kind of Meta Data to the RAW stream. Because encoding could indroduce delay and also raw stream bandwith sending. Could u explain why this are needed both. Never Heard that a uncompressed Stream is send over Network

I need to use the two streams in sync in the same way audio and video can be synchronised by a sink. My thinking is that if it can be done with audio and video thanks to RTP it must be feasible with my use case too.

Before going to deep in this rabbit hole, why do you need this? When you say you want to Access the "raw data of the h264 Stream" this data you already have in the uncompressed Stream ? Or are this two diffrent Video streams Like h264 Shows a different scene as the uncompressed Stream ?

The two streams contain different data. The h.264 stream contains video whilst the uncompressed stream contains pure data which is not video nor audio, just our own data. At some point in our app we need access to this data and the decoded h.264, in sync. I know how to get to the decoded data, but I am not sure how to synchrosize the two.

OK so when you package the streams did you mux them together ? In rtsp you could have a data Stream. Like in Axis cameras where you can get rtsp stream with two packed streams one for Video and one for onvif metadata whats just a bytestream. Maybe this helps you https://discourse.gstreamer.org/t/how-create-metadata-stream-like-network-camera/1346.

Thanks, this post is very helpful. I was not aware of rtpgstpay. And no, the streams are not muxed, we use gst-rtsp-server to send two separate RTP streams.

OK glad to help
